# Eclipse gradle refresh from cmd

Tags: java, eclipse, cmd, gradle, command

I wondered if there is a cmd command for refreshing an eclipse gradle project?
Normally you would `right-click -> gradle -> refresh -> refresh all`. 
I am looking for something like gradlew project:`refresh eclipse`, to be able to update projects using a `.bat` file.
Cheers :)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you are integrating with Eclipse. If you are using the project file generation approach, just run `gradlew eclipse` (or `gradlew cleanEclipse eclipse`) another time, then hit F5 to refresh the Eclipse project. If you are using the Eclipse plugin (also known as Eclipse Gradle integration), you can only refresh in the IDE, in the way you already described (but perhaps you could assign a shortcut).

Answer (score 0):

Reading a documentation can give you the answer - http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html

Just apply the `eclipse` plugin in your gradle buildscript(s) and you will be able to run `gradle eclipse` from command line.

Comment: This command generates the files so you can import the project into eclipse, I dont think it's refreshing an existing project:
"Generates all Eclipse configuration files"